# reservation application, problem appear reservation on all devices

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, express, ngrok

so first this is an reservation app for units. the code of a single unit is the following:

```
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  Alert,
  Switch,
  StyleSheet,
  Modal,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

const Unit = (props) => {
  const [isSwitchEnabled, setSwitch] = React.useState(true);
  const [isModalVisible, setModal] = React.useState(false);
  const [isReserveButtonVisible, setVisibilty] = useState(true);
  const [isCancelButtonVisible, setVisibilty2] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal transparent={true} visible={isModalVisible} animationType="slide">
        <View style={styles.modalView1}>
          <View style={styles.modalView2}>
            <Text>Please enter a password to reserve the unit </Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.modalInput} placeholder="e.g. 56426" />
            <Button
              title="Save"
              onPress={() => {
                setSwitch(false), setModal(false), setVisibilty(false);
                setVisibilty2(true),
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    setSwitch(true), setModal(false), setVisibilty(true);
                    setVisibilty2(false),
                      Alert.alert(
                        "Unfortunately the reservation time ran out and no vehicle has arrived at the station so the reservation was cancelled."
                      );
                  }, 20000);
              }}
            />
            <Button
              title="Cancel"
              onPress={() => {
                setModal(false);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      <>
        {isReserveButtonVisible ? (
          <Button
            title="Click here to reserve"
            visible={isReserveButtonVisible}
            onPress={() => {
              Alert.alert(
                "Please be noted that the unit is reserved for the next hour only ",
                ".",
                [
                  {
                    text: "Reserve",
                    onPress: () => {
                      setModal(true);
                    },
                  },
                  { text: "Cancel" },
                ]
              );
            }}
          />
        ) : null}
        {isCancelButtonVisible ? (
          <Button
            title="Click here to cancel"
            visible={isCancelButtonVisible}
            onPress={() => {
              Alert.alert(
                "Please be noted that now you are canceling your reservation",
                ".",
                [
                  {
                    text: "Yes",
                    onPress: () => {
                      setSwitch(true), setVisibilty(true);
                      setVisibilty2(false);
                    },
                  },
                  { text: "No" },
                ]
              );
            }}
          />
        ) : null}
      </>
      <Switch value={isSwitchEnabled} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalView1: {
    backgroundColor: "#000000aa",
    flex: 1,
  },
  modalView2: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    margin: 50,
    padding: 40,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  modalInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#777",
    padding: 8,
    margin: 10,
    width: 200,
  },
});

export default Unit;
```

and there are many units but they all work in same way so the reservation page in the app code is the following:

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import Unit from "../codes/Unit";

const Reservation = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Unit title="AC unit 1" />
      <Unit title="AC unit 2" />
      <Unit title="AC unit 3" />
      <Unit title="DC unit 1" />
      <Unit title="DC unit 2" />
      <Unit title="DC unit 3" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Reservation;
```

both codes are working

the idea is if you noticed in the unit code I put a switch so that if the user follow the reservation steps it the end the unit will be reserved for him and the switch will be closed  and this is working.

what I need is that when one user reserve a unit this unit appeares reserved already on all other devices in other words no one else can reserve it as long as it is reserved

I am trying with json server and ngrok and also tried with express and mangodb i just dont how to make this happen

please in help and tell me what line to write so that the data can be exported and imported on all the devices

thanks in advance and sorry for long post

Comment: sounds like you'd need a websocket to update the client in real time about changes to the database

Comment: okeh how do i do that